# ACF fields displaying in the theme

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, advanced-custom-fields

I need to display my AFC fields in my theme. my theme owner say me You should edit single-room-type.php file. But i couldn't find where should i add my ACF codes in this file. i think i must edit another file. Any ideas how to do this?

```
<section class="content-editor">
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
        return;
    }
    ?>

        <?php do_action( 'mphb_render_single_room_type_before_content' ); ?>

        <?php
        /**
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderTitle              - 10
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderFeaturedImage      - 20
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderDescription        - 30
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderPrice              - 40
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderAttributes         - 50
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderCalendar           - 60
         * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderReservationForm    - 70
         */
        //do_action( 'mphb_render_single_room_type_content' );
        ?>

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'mphb_render_single_room_type_after_content' ); ?>

<?php
endwhile;
?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//-----------------------------------------------------
// Single Output
//-----------------------------------------------------
if(is_single()){ ?>
  <section class="content-editor">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Add your acf field here -->
        <div class="your-acf-field"><?php echo get_field('your_acf_field', 
          get_the_ID());?></div>

        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </section>
 <?php } else {
```

Comment: i add my code but it is look top of the page. 
actually i want to edit this file 
" * @hooked \MPHB\Views\SingleRoomTypeView::renderDescription        - 30 " but i couldn't find out where this file is.

Comment: You need to find the file where this function is located mphb_render_single_room_type_content() in your main theme. What is the name of your theme? Its kinda hard for me to know where to edit if I cant see the folder structure of your theme. If you could upload the main theme in github then I might be able to find where you should edit the file. Or maybe a screenshot but it will be hard for both of us.

Comment: There should be a file with the name "single" or similar in you main theme. If I could just see the folder structure then I'd be able to help.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answer. yes i know i should find this file but i couldn't. i guess there is not this file. my theme name: bellevue-Hotel + Bed and Breakfast Booking Calendar Theme. it is a licensed theme. if I upload it to github it may be a problem.

Comment: can you confirm the folder name of your theme? is it bellevue?

Comment: can you share the link of your theme page?

Comment: theme link: https://themeforest.net/item/bellevue-hotel-bed-breakfast-booking-theme/12482898

Comment: Hi again, I think I found the file where you can add your ACF field. You need to copy this file from your main theme folder to your child theme folder (wp-content/themes/bellevue/templates/room.php). Make sure that you have the same folder structure, meaning you have to create the templates folder. Your child theme folder structure should look like this (wp-content/themes/your-child-theme/templates/room.php). I updated my answer above to where you can add your acf field.

Comment: thanks a lot for interesting but I give up use ACF.

Comment: If I could just see your code. I'd be able to help you. I'm sure the file is just sitting there somewhere. I mean ACF is really awesome plugin to use.